# AngularJS ng-messages with ng-message-include not showing

Tags: angularjs

I have search a lot on Internet, but i did not get my program workable. so, i am choose stackoverflow for my question. Basically i want to display validation error message whenever validation fail. For this i am using ngMessage directive to make error message centralized so that i can update any error message easily. But the messages not showing up. Here is my code:

```
Index.php
<div  class="alert alert-danger field-wrapper errors">
   <div ng-messages ="loginForm.email.$error"><div ng-messages-include="ng-errorMessages.php"></div></div>
   <div ng-messages ="loginForm.password.$error"><div ng-messages-include="ng-errorMessages.php"></div></div>
</div>
```

Here is my message file code:

```
ng-errorMessages.php
<div ng-messages for="loginForm.email.$error">
    <div ng-message ng-show="required">Email is required!</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="email">Email is not vang-messaged format!</div>
</div>
<div ng-messages for="loginForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-message ng-show="minlength">Password is too short!</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="maxlength">Password is too long</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="required">Password is required!</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="!required && passwordWeak">Password is weak!</div>
</div>
```

No the issue is, Nothing showing up. When i inspect element in chrome i got this output:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger field-wrapper errors">
        <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error" class="ng-inactive"><!-- ngMessagesInclude: ng-errorMessages.php --><div ng-messages="" for="loginForm.email.$error" class="ng-scope ng-inactive">
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
    </div>
        <div ng-messages="" for="loginForm.password.$error" class="ng-scope ng-inactive">
            <!-- ngMessage:  -->
            <!-- ngMessage:  -->
            <!-- ngMessage:  -->
            <!-- ngMessage:  -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" class="ng-inactive"><!-- ngMessagesInclude: ng-errorMessages.php --><div ng-messages="" for="loginForm.email.$error" class="ng-scope ng-inactive">
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="" for="loginForm.password.$error" class="ng-scope ng-inactive">
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
        <!-- ngMessage:  -->
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Please friends help me out. here is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jwun3jzuqgkES9sRhR8Q?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my finding, Refer this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TrXX9nN6Lal8vnIEDtDe?p=preview)

I changed this part to

```
<div class="alert alert-danger field-wrapper errors">
  <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="ng-errorMessages.html"></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="ng-errorMessages.html"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to in index.html file:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger field-wrapper errors">
  <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error || loginForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="ng-errorMessages.html"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
<div ng-messages for="loginForm.email.$error">
    <div ng-message ng-show="required">Email is required!</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="email">Email is not vang-messaged format!</div>
</div>
<div ng-messages for="loginForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-message ng-show="minlength">Password is too short!</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="maxlength">Password is too long</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="required">Password is required!</div>
    <div ng-message ng-show="!required && passwordWeak">Password is weak!</div>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div ng-messages for="loginForm.email.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Email is required!</div>
    <div ng-message="email">Email is not vang-messaged format!</div>
</div>
<div ng-messages for="loginForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-message="minlength">Password is too short!</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Password is too long</div>
    <div ng-message="required">Password is required!</div>
    <div ng-message="!required && passwordWeak">Password is weak!</div>
</div>
```

And its working fine with ng-messages-include.

Comment: Yes it is working. if i want to display as ul li than what to do?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, display the messages in ul>li ?

Comment: Actually these messages are displying inside div. I want all message should in li under one ul.

Comment: I think the last message with the required and password has to be `ng-message-exp` since it's an expression.